# laravel api route is not redirecting?

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel,I had wrote api route code to register controller:

`Route::post('test','Api\Auth\RegisterController@index');`

In Register controller i had written simple code

```
public function index(Request $request)
{
    return 'hello';
}
```

I am getting the output in postman like:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

not hello.

Here the images:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gDTjj.png%60) [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKYwa.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Routes defined in the routes/api.php file are nested within a route
>   group by the RouteServiceProvider. Within this group, the /api URI
>   prefix is automatically applied so you do not need to manually apply
>   it to every route in the file.

You are trying to make a request to a route which does not exist.

**In Postman**

Change:

```
http://localhost:8080/App/api/test
```

To:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/test
```

Comment: @creativecoder please accept the answer if it helped you

Comment: how to get reputation i can't vote to your answer its saying 15 reputation is required.

Comment: @creativecoder read this https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation and it's okay If you can't upvote just yet. You'll be able to do that soon enough if you keep asking good questions and posting good answers

Answer (score 0):

You're telling laravel to route assoaciate '/api/test', not '/App/api/test', which is the adress you're trying to reach.

Also, if you plan to reach that address straight from the location bar of your browser, you should register the 'GET' method as well.

Comment: sorry i didn't get

Comment: The OP has defined his routes in api.php so shouldn't he access the `api/test` route?

Comment: @SapneshNaik Indeed

Answer (score 0):

As you are returning something in function you need to use route as get() instead of post().

```
Route::get('test','Api\Auth\RegisterController@index');
```